# Replace odd digits with 4 recursive function

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I need to create a recursive function which replaces all odd digits to a 4.

Example

User enters: 2391
Output: 2444

Please use beginner C++ language, no array and etc. Using basic C++ language and recursive would be truly helpful thanks.

```
int oddToFour(int num) {
    int digit = num % 10; 
    if (digit / 2 != 0) return 4;
    else return digit; 
    oddToFour(num/10); 
}
```

Comment: You have very specific needs for solving this. So, you bring out the recursion, and we'll help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count specific digits and replace even digits with 0 using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343912/count-specific-digits-and-replace-even-digits-with-0-using-recursion) posted just 10 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
int oddToFour(int num) {
    if (num == 0) 
        return 0; 

    int digit = num % 10; 
    if (digit % 2 == 1) 
        digit = 4; 

    return oddToFour(num/10) * 10 + digit; 
}
```

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: @Damien Why? I have tested it before posting. Check here: https://ideone.com/IixNJT

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake